# View is not passing values to the model which is in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I am using ViewModel and want to update record against a specific ID in the database using asp.net MVC but when I press submit button model is empty in the controller which means data is not passing to the controller from view against that specific Id.

```
    //Controller
    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

            public ActionResult EditCustomer([Bind(Include = "Customer_Id,Customer_Name,Address,Description")] CustomerVM customerVM)
            {
                var CustomerData = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Customer_Id == customerVM.Customer_Id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (CustomerData != null)
                {
                    CustomerData.Customer_Name = customerVM.Customer_Name;
                    CustomerData.Address = customerVM.Address;
                    CustomerData.Description = customerVM.Description;
                    db.Entry(CustomerData).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("CustomerList");
            }


    //ViewModel
     public class CustomerVM
        {
            public int Customer_Id { get; set; }
            public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string Industry_Type { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Updated_By { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated_Date { get; set; }
            public string Created_By { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> Creatd_Date { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Are all the name attributes in your from elements correct - matching the model property names?

Comment: yes they are same

Comment: If you look at the incoming form (in the debugger in the POST method) is the data correct? Are there any model validation errors?

Comment: yes there in no errors when i return the view from edit get method but when i post the view against edit then nothing bind in model.

Comment: mmm, can we see the view